# How to get rid of every column that are filled with zero from a Pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torchtext

I have a pytorch tensor `A` like below:

```
A = 
tensor([[  4,   3,   3,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [ 13,   4,  13,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [707, 707,   4,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  7,   7,   7,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
        [195, 195, 195,  ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

I would like to:

- identify all the columns whose all of its entries are equal to 0
- delete only those columns that has all of their entries equal to 0

I can imagine doing:

```
zero_list = []
for j in range(A.size()[1]):
    if torch.sum(A[:,j]) == 0:
         zero_list = zero_list.append(j)
```

to identify the columns that only has 0 for its elements
but I am not sure how to delete such columns filled with 0 from the original tensor.

How can I delete the columns with zero from a pytorch tensor based on the index number?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes more sense to index the columns you want to keep instead of what you want to delete.

```
valid_cols = []
for col_idx in range(A.size(1)):
    if not torch.all(A[:, col_idx] == 0):
        valid_cols.append(col_idx)
A = A[:, valid_cols]
```

Or a little more cryptically

```
valid_cols = [col_idx for col_idx, col in enumerate(torch.split(A, 1, dim=1)) if not torch.all(col == 0)]
A = A[:, valid_cols]
```

Answer (score 7):

> Identify all the columns whose all of its entries are equal to 0

`non_empty_mask = A.abs().sum(dim=0).bool()`

This sums up over the absolute values of each column and then converts the result to a boolean, i.e. `False` if the sum is zero and `True` otherwise.

> Delete only those columns that has all of their entries equal to 0

`A[:,non_empty_mask]`

This simply applies the mask to the original tensor, i.e. it keeps the rows where `non_empty_mask` is `True`.